# addEventListener and control flow

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, control-flow

Basically, when I put an addEventListener in my code, does the script stop executing until the event happens and gets listened or the code keeps getting executed no matter what?

I mean, if an event that I want to listen and that is placed at the start of my script does not happen, does it block my whole script?

If you can, don't just answer yes or no, I would be glad if you could tell what the interpreter does in those situations.

Comment: The code keeps running. When the event occurs, the callback function runs.

Comment: but why is that?
I thought it would act like a function call.

Comment: Why do you think it won't? You could confirm your own suspicions by writing some example code. Please read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: being a newbie, I thought that it would act like a function call.

Comment: Not *immediately* when the event happens. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: In what way? If the code ran immediately it wouldn't be waiting for the event

Comment: If it waited, how could you create event listeners for multiple inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript eventloop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

The following link would explain you well. if still you are having problem feel free to ask.